# How to add kube-config and use go-client in our go program

Tags: go, kubernetes, kubeconfig

What the role of kube-Config and how to use this in our go program for simple operations?

Answer (score 1):

There is an example in [`client-go`](https://github.com/kubernetes/client-go/) library you can use for learning. You can check [`the source`](https://github.com/kubernetes/client-go/blob/master/examples/out-of-cluster-client-configuration/main.go), i am not including it here, as it a bit heavy.

But in general:

- You read config from kubeconfig using `kubernetes.NewForConfig`
- And using `clientset` returned by the previous command your app performing API requests.